# How to split a decimal number in lua script?

Tags: split, lua, scripting

I need to split the balance (decimal value) in to two part.

```
 Like 6678.9999  to
 6678 and 9999
```

So my final array will be value[0] = 6678 and value[1] = 9999

Is it possible in lua with decimal,I can do with string.

Can any one guide for me ?

Comment: Try [this code](http://ideone.com/MVTylC) or [this one](http://ideone.com/fwXOxd).

Comment: Or [this one](http://ideone.com/mEBjK4)?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible in lua with decimal,I can do with string.

The problem is, floating point numbers are usually not precise, due to the fact that computers use binary system. For example:

```
print(6678.9999 % 1)
```

The output is `0.9998999999998`, not `0.9999`.

So the best way is probably still string manipulation:

```
string.match(tostring(6678.9999), "([^.]*)%.([^.]*)")
```

Comment: That is what I suggested.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So? The OP knows how to do with string. The main part of my answer is why manipulating with numbers directly isn't a good idea. The code is only for completeness. For the record, I didn't read your comment under the question before answering, I'm capable of wring this one line of code myself.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew where? Link-only is not an answer, sorry.

Comment: its need to i need to play the value like 6678 dollers and 9999 cents. that is why it is needed.And thanks its working...

Comment: Perhaps the pattern should be `([^.]*)%.?([^.]*)` for cases where you have no decimal. If the value tips 6679  you will get nil. In my case, the first match will return